# How to deal in Android with RESTful API that throws HTML table

Tags: java, api, android-studio

[This](http://api.verbix.com/conjugator/html?language=spa&tableurl=http://tools.verbix.com/webverbix/personal/template.htm&verb=ser) API returns a whole HTML table. I'm searching how to add this table (as is) into my UI but I've never seen such API throwing HTM table.
Browsing Internet for an answer is not giving me any hope either.
Is it possible to put it into a webview? or any other UI object? 
My application sends a word to the API, and I'm getting the table in return.
I'd appreciate some code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly just show that exact same page in a WebView. If you want to parse the table and display only certain information, there is a library call JSOUP that is available which makes it very convenient to parse HTML.

It looks like you don't mind displaying the whole thing in a WebView - if that is acceptable, then you just load the page into a WebView widget. WebView will take care of rendering the page exactly as you see it in a browser. You only have to tell it what to load.

Comment: I got it working. Thank you ! I see the whole page in the WebView now, I will have a look at JSOUP too. Appreciated

Comment: Good to know. If this worked for you, can you mark this as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You parse the output like you would any other web request. If you wanted to include the table in your own webpage, you could. Or you could parse the response for the specific info you need.

Don't think of it as an API, think of it as a URL you're requesting and now you need to do something with the contents. That might help with your Googling. You're essentially doing page scraping.

Comment: You are right. it helped with the Googling. I put it into a WebView and it is working now. This is part of the code 'webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, result, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);' Thank you kindly !!